# Finding the equation of a parabola

Tags: analytic-geometry, conic-sections

Find the equation of the parabola in standard form which passes through the points $(-2,1)$, $(1,2)$ and $(-1,3)$ with axis parallel to the x-axis.

Hint: Use the form $y^2 + Dx + Ey + F = 0$.

Comment: It would be nice for you to tell others what progress you've made. Also where did you encounter a problem in your try?

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:** Plug the three points in the equation and you will get three linear equations for three unknowns, which should be easily solved.

Answer (score 1):

You get this inhomogeneous linear system in $D, E, F$:
$$
A x = b \iff
\begin{pmatrix}
-2 & 1 & 1 \\
 1 & 2 & 1 \\
-1 & 3 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
D \\
E \\
F
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
-1 \\
-4 \\
-9
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Solving in Octave:

```
>> A = [-2,1,1; 1,2,1;-1,3,1]
A =

  -2   1   1
   1   2   1
  -1   3   1

>> b = [-1;-4;-9]
b =

  -1
  -4
  -9

>> inv(A)
ans =

  -0.20000   0.40000  -0.20000
  -0.40000  -0.20000   0.60000
   1.00000   1.00000  -1.00000

>> x = inv(A) * b
x =

   0.40000
  -4.20000
   4.00000
```

Asking my friend Ruby, if those parameters work:

```
irb> def f(x,y) y**2 + 0.4 * x + -4.2 * y + 4 end
=> :f
irb> f(-2,1)
=> 0.0
irb> f(1,2)
=> 0.0
irb> f(-1,3)
=> -1.7763568394002505e-15
```